# Example where spectrum of $AB \neq BA$ in a general unital Banach Algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

I am looking for an example where the spectrum of $AB \neq BA$ in a general unital Banach algebra. Now I have shown that the spectrums coincide if we ignore 0, so the only way the spectrums can be different is if AB is invertible but BA is not invertible, but finding specific examples of where this occurs seems to be rare.

Answer (score 2):

In the bounded linear operators on $\ell^2$, let $A$ and $B$ be left and right shifts.